# Azure AD B2C Why Display Control on password reset for email verification is not rendered?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I followed the sample in the documentation to integrate custom email through DisplayControl on the signin and signup flow. This flow works as described.

I am also using the reset password flow. It should use the same custom email so I tried to transfer the changes from the signin/up flow to the password reset flow.

The VerificationDisplayControl is not rendered on the page!

What I changed: In TechnicalProfile *LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress* I added

```
<DisplayClaims>
  <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
</DisplayClaims>
```

reusing the already present configuration.

What did I miss? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you updated the content definition page contract version for that technical profile which supports display controls.

```xml
<Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
```

```xml
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.0.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account change password page</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
```